# How to create a secured/private WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to create a WCF service that may be accessed only on localhost.
I couldn't find any reference for that, is that possible?
All the posts I had found talked about this scenario as a bug, well I'd like it as a feature.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without asking why, I'd suggest hosting WCF in a windows service and controlling the port locally.

Comment: Hi guys, thank your for a timely responses. What I'm trying to do is to create an internal service to initialize a set of databases using EF code first feature. I need it to be private as database initialization is most probably a development process and I wouldn't want to expose such an option to the outside world. I'd be happy to try other ideas. The thing is that I need to create a set of databases from time to time as we are still in a stage that tables may change from time to time

Comment: Databases will change (even in production), so I'd form a plan around how to manage the schema upgrades (EF Data Migrations is one option).

Answer (score 3):

If you're flexible on protocols, you could use a netNamedPipeBinding hosted in a Windows service.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the binding for the web site it is attached to and change it to `localhost`, rather than `*`. If you are hosting other services that need external access you can always create a new web site on a different port, such as `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 1):

A WCF service should be agnostic about how it's hosted or accessed.

Whatever's hosting the service, on the other hand, determines how the service can be accessed.

As Mike Goodwin suggested, having your host only allow netNamedPipeBinding will restrict the service to only be accessible via the machine that the host is running on.

Here's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) on the various transport protocols, including named pipes.

Here's a pretty in depth [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) on hosting WCF services.

Comment: Hi guys, thank your for a timely responses. What I'm trying to do is to create an internal service to initialize a set of databases using EF code first feature. I need it to be private as database initialization is most probably a development process and I wouldn't want to expose such an option to the outside world. I'd be happy to try other ideas. The thing is that I need to create a set of databases from time to time as we are still in a stage that tables may change from time to time

Comment: You might want to stick this comment up under your question.  :)  Since it's meant for everyone trying to help, and not just me.  :)